# Retain rows with data that is more recent than specified time

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with pandas df, and I want to retain the rows with ['start_time'] column values more recent than the days_range_to_retain variable.

In the code below, old_df is the df I am working with, and current_date is a datetime.date() object. The line is meant to calculate the difference between the current_date and the date stored in the start_time column of the old_df. Then I compare the difference to days_range_to_retain:

```
df_removed = old_df[(current_date - (old_df.start_time).date()).days <= days_range_to_retain]
```

The error I get is:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'date'
```

How can I retain the rows of the df based on this conditional?

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: If the `start_time` column is already a column of datetimes or Timestamps, why are you calling `date()`? Your problem is that `old_df.start_time` is a `Series` object.

Comment: @blorgon How would I call it otherwise? When I do old_df.start_time, it gives me the following error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'datetime.date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line by:

```
df_removed  = old_df[(current_date - old_df.start_time.dt.date).dt.days
                         <= days_range_to_retain]
```

You need to use `.dt` accessor.